# How can I replace the entries of a tensor with the appropriate ranking of each entry?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, ranking, tensor

suppose that I have the following tensor:

```
>> i = 3
>> j = 5
>> k = 2
>> sor = torch.randn(i,j,k)

>> sor
Out[20]: 
tensor([[[ 0.5604, -0.9675],
         [-1.0953, -0.5615],
         [ 0.4250, -0.9176],
         [-1.6188, -1.0217],
         [-0.0778,  1.9407]],

        [[-0.1034, -0.7925],
         [-0.2955,  0.8058],
         [-0.5349,  1.1040],
         [ 1.1240,  0.8249],
         [ 0.0827, -1.2471]],

        [[ 0.5924,  0.4777],
         [-2.4640, -1.9527],
         [-0.4519,  0.4788],
         [-0.2308, -0.2368],
         [-1.6786,  0.1360]]])
```

suppose that for every fixed `i` and `j`, I want to compute the numeric rank of elements across `k`, and replace the elements of the tensor `sor` with those ranks. For instance, from the example above, I want to change the entry `[ 0.5604, -0.9675]`, which is `sor[0,0,:]` , into `[1, 2]`, since `0.5604 > -0.9675`

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`torch.argsort`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.argsort):

```py
torch.argsort(sor, dim=2)

Out[ ]:
tensor([[[1, 0],
         [0, 1],
         [1, 0],
         [0, 1],
         [0, 1]],

        [[1, 0],
         [0, 1],
         [0, 1],
         [1, 0],
         [1, 0]],

        [[1, 0],
         [0, 1],
         [0, 1],
         [1, 0],
         [0, 1]]])
```